# tikz-3d/pgfplots: How to draw/plot curved spacetime?

Tags: pgfplots, asymptote, tikz-3d

Since I try to write a short introduction to tensors for physics students, I mentioned the Einstein's field equations (as a motivation).
Therefore, I wanted to create a tikzpicture/pgfplots of curved spacetime.
First, I created a 3d plot that looks familiar with the most common picture of curved spacetime

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    hide axis = true,
    x domain = -1.5:1.5,
    zmin = -2.5,
    zmax = 2.5
    ]    
    \addplot3 [
        surf, 
        faceted color = lightgray,
        fill = white, 
        line width = 0.1pt,
        samples = 50] {-1.5*exp(-0.5*(x^2+y^2))};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives me

[image]

But actually, this is not the best representation for curved spacetime, since this picture only shows the curvature in one direction (here, along the z-axis).
A much better visualization would be something
[like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8h1c7ToC9w) (YouTube Animation) or [this](https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc/?page=40).

I found that something like `\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}` might help here, but I am still a beginner when it comes to tikz/pgfplots.

Thank you in advance for all your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- An almost plain Ti*k*Z one (only needs the `perspective` library for the `3d view`):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={120}{30},samples=51,domain=-2.5:2.5]
\foreach\i in {-2.5,-2.25,...,2.5}
{% curved spacetime
  \draw[gray] plot (\x,\i,{2.5-0.5*exp(-0.75*(\x*\x+\i*\i))});
  \draw[gray] plot (\i,\x,{2.5-0.5*exp(-0.75*(\x*\x+\i*\i))});
  \draw[gray] plot (\x,{2.5-0.5*exp(-0.75*(\x*\x+\i*\i))},\i);
  \draw[gray] plot (\i,{2.5-0.5*exp(-0.75*(\x*\x+\i*\i))},\x);
  \draw[gray] plot ({2.5-0.5*exp(-0.75*(\x*\x+\i*\i))},\x,\i);
  \draw[gray] plot ({2.5-0.5*exp(-0.75*(\x*\x+\i*\i))},\i,\x);
}% axes
\draw[thick,-latex] (2,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[left]  {$x$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,2,0) -- (0,5,0) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,2) -- (0,0,5) node[above] {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- And a `pgfplots` version:

```
\documentclass[border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.1pt]
\begin{axis}
[
  hide axis=true,
  domain=-2.5:2.5,
  zmin=-2.5,zmax=2.5,
  samples=50,
  z buffer=sort
]    
\addplot3[surf,faceted color=lightgray,fill=white] {2.5-1.5*exp(-0.5*(x^2+y^2))};
\addplot3[surf,faceted color=lightgray,fill=white] ({2.5-1.5*exp(-0.5*(x^2+y^2))},x,y);
\addplot3[surf,faceted color=lightgray,fill=white] (x,{-2.5+1.5*exp(-0.5*(x^2+y^2))},y);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]